# How to make deep copy of java object without using serialization ?

Tags: java, deep-copy

Is it possible to make a deep copy/clone of a Java object without using serialization ? If so then how ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Short of reflection (if even that), there's no way to make a deep copy of an arbitrary object, period.  To use serialization the object must be serializable.

Comment: suppose i am trying to create a generic immutable collection, where i don't know if the elements implement serializable but once created 
you can't add, remove or even update/change an element but you can get a reference of an element using peek() (In short they become read-only from outside). So, i was thinking maybe deep clone and return the cloned object on peek() ?

Comment: It's not the responsibility of the collection to make its elements immutable. It's the responsibility of the class of the elements itself, or of the user of the collection (which could store read-only adapters of a mutable class, for example). The collection shouldn't bother with that.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that it is not the responsibility of the collection class. But i am asking if it's possible? Suppose, this Collection that i am creating will take some other collection of mutable objects/elements when constructed and create a wrapper such that you can only access those elements for read only purpose but you can't change these elements. 
i was thinking about returning a copy of the element when trying to access any element. What do you think? I am just curious . :)

Comment: You would have to put in a lot of assumptions about the objects you are copying for the concept "deep copy" to even make sense, let alone be feasible. In other words, **no**, there is no generic solution as you envision it.

Comment: I agree with Marko and Hot Licks. It's not possible.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/cloning/ 
this deep cloning library might do the trick ! :)

Comment: Bringing this back from the dead... What about `security concerns`?! Maybe I do not want my `class` to be `Serializable` because of security concerns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`Java Deep-Cloning Library`](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/) to make deep copies of objects. It is really useful when you can't (or don't want) to make your classes serializable. The use is straight-forward:

```
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();

MyClass clone = cloner.deepClone(o);
// clone is a deep-clone of o
```

Comment: After using this API my JVM get crashes and getting following error

*** Error in `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0_openjdk/bin/java': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f250c140b10 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81609)[0x7f2563519609]

Comment: What about `security concerns`?! Maybe I do not want my `class` to be `Serializable` because of security concerns? How does that library achieve cloning underneath, does it also use `Serializable` at some point?

Comment: Reading the code at the Github link, it creates a new instance of an object of the same class (using `org.objenesis.instantiator.ObjectInstantiator;`), and copies all the fields recursively, making some optimizations/assumptions based on collection type if applicable.